# Where does mercurial get its meaning?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I'm curious where the word "mercurial" derives its meaning? Two guesses I have are the Roman god Mercury, and the chemical element mercury. I'm leaning towards the latter... because the word "quicksilver" shares its meaning, and it refers to the chemical element, not the Roman god. But I would love to have someone confirm this if possible!

Edit: I'm referring to the definition: "quick to change in mood and behavior".

Comment: Which definition of *mercurial* are you referring to? Both your guesses are correct: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mercurial *1. Pertaining to the planet Mercury  2.Pertaining to the Roman god Mercury  4.  Of, or pertaining to the element mercury*

Comment: Your question would be improved if you would quote and link the etymologies provided in the dictionaries you have checked.

Comment: @choster the OP doesn't mention anything about dictionaries, definitions nor etymologies in his post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's exactly my point.

Comment: @choster but he doesn't say he has checked any! He talks about guesses. Not everyone knows about the existence of *etymonline*. And not every online dictionary has an entry about origins. You could say the OP didn't do any research.

Comment: I'm closevoting because it seems the OP didn't do any research

Comment: Good guess, @ktm5124, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mercurial&searchmode=none shows that all the definitions converge on the the shared name of the planet and the god Mercury. Not such a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/mercurial):

> Meaning "sprightly, volatile, quick" (1590s) is from supposed qualities of those born under the planet Mercury (they also are the qualities of the god Mercury), probably also partly by association with the qualities of quicksilver.

Note that quicksilver (mercury) is the only metal that is liquid at room temperature, and so is elusive and mobile (and also bright and flashy in light).

Comment: I see. So it has to do with the planet and the god. I'm curious though... did the chemical element mercury derive its name from the same source? (Planet, god?)

Comment: This is part of a larger system of humoral psychology. Each of the four humors not only corresponded with one of the four elements of Empedocles, but also was associated with one or two astrological planets. Temperaments formerly associated with the predominance of the various humors are to this day sometimes described by adjectives derived from planet names, as *jovial* or (much more rarely) *saturnine.* The *mercurial* disposition was thought to be one in which various humors predominated by turns.

Answer (score 1):

> **MERCURIAL** (*adj*.)
>
> Mercurial late 14c., "pertaining to the planet Mercury" (see Mercury). Meaning "sprightly, volatile, quick" (1590s) is from supposed qualities of those born under the planet Mercury (they also are the qualities of the god Mercury), probably also partly by association with the qualities of quicksilver. A variant in this sense was *mercurious* (1590s). Related: *Mercurially*; *mercuriality*. From etymonline [link](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mercurial+&searchmode=nl)
>
> **Mercurial**
>
> Derived from Mercury (/ˈmɜrkjʉri/); Latin: Mercurius is a major Roman god, being one of the Dii Consentes within the ancient Roman pantheon. He is the patron god of financial gain, commerce, eloquence (and thus poetry), messages/communication (including divination), travelers, boundaries, luck, trickery and thieves; he is also the guide of souls to the underworld. He was considered the son of Maia and Jupiter in Roman mythology. His name is possibly related to the Latin word merx ("merchandise"; compare merchant, commerce, etc.), mercari (to trade), and merces (wages); another possible connection is the Proto-Indo-European root merĝ- for "boundary, border" (cf. Old English "mearc", Old Norse "mark" and Latin "margō") and Greek οὖρος (by analogy of Arctūrus/Ἀρκτοῦρος), as the "keeper of boundaries," referring to his role as bridge between the upper and lower worlds.
>
> **Mercury** has influenced the name of many things in a variety of scientific fields, such as the planet Mercury, and the element mercury. The word ***mercurial*** is commonly used to refer to something or someone erratic, volatile or unstable, ***derived from Mercury's swift flights from place to place***.
>
> From Wikipedia [**Mercury(mythology)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(mythology))

conceptually related ...

> **Proteus**
>
> In Greek mythology, Proteus (/ˈproʊtiəs, -tjuːs/;[1] Greek: Πρωτεύς) is an early sea-god or god of rivers and oceanic bodies of water, one of several deities whom Homer calls the "Old Man of the Sea". [2] ***Some who ascribe to him a specific domain call him the god of "elusive sea change", which suggests the constantly changing nature of the sea or the liquid quality of water in general.*** He can foretell the future, but, in a mytheme familiar to several cultures, will change his shape to avoid having to; he will answer only to someone who is capable of capturing him. ***From this feature of Proteus comes the adjective protean, with the general meaning of "versatile", "mutable", "capable of assuming many forms"***. "Protean" has positive connotations of *flexibility*, *versatility* and *adaptability*.
>
> **In alchemy and psychology**
>
> The German mystical alchemist Heinrich Khunrath wrote of the shape-changing sea-god who, because of his relationship to the sea, is both a symbol of the unconscious as well as the perfection of the art. Alluding to the scintilla, the spark from ‘the light of nature’ and symbol of the anima mundi, Khunrath in Gnostic vein stated of the Protean element Mercury:
>
> our Catholick Mercury, by virtue of his universal fiery spark of the light of nature, is beyond doubt Proteus, the sea god of the ancient pagan sages, who hath the key to the sea and …power over all things.-—Von Hyleanischen Chaos, Carl Jung, vol. 14:50[better source needed]
>
> In modern times, the Swiss psychologist Carl Jung defined the mythological figure of Proteus as a personification of the unconscious, who, ***because of his gift of prophecy and shape-changing, has much in common with the central but elusive figure of alchemy, Mercurius.***
>
> From Wikipedia [**Protean/Proteus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteus)

Comment: ktm5124, mercurial/mercurius is the quintessential element of the occidental proto-science known as "Alchemy", from which we derive the name and some of the sensibilities of modern chemistry.